# Typo3 (6.2.11) Bug: columns in page view, can't add new content (add icon hides on mouseover)

Tags: web, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

[image: pageview]

When I want to click the Add Icon, the icon hides away and the pageview itself is looking strange. Anay ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what caused the problem:

Uninstalling the extension "gridelements" was the problem.
After reinstalling the extension, the pageview is working as expected. (But I have not found a solution to fix the problem itself)

Comment: Most likely the JS and CSS files that where merged still contained the old files content.